# How can I get the derived primitive type from a generic interface?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Been struggling with this for a bit so wanted to see if someone here might know the solution. I have a set of interfaces (and an implementation):

```cs
public interface IInputValue
{
}

public interface IInputValue<T> : IInputValue where T : struct
{
    T Value { get; set; }
}

public class ButtonInputValue : IInputValue<bool>
{
    private bool m_Value;
    public bool Value
    {
        get => m_Value;
        set => m_Value = value;
    }
}
```

And then I have a scriptable object class that inherits and uses implementations of `IInputValue<T>`.

```cs
public abstract class InputTrigger : ScriptableObject
{
}

public abstract class InputTrigger<T> : InputTrigger where T : IInputValue
{
    public abstract T InputValue { get; }
}
```

`T` for example, could be `ButtonInputValue`. I want to serialize this scriptable object in another class (as `InputTrigger`) and simply be able to call `.InputValue` on it to get the correct derived type of `IInputValue` or just get the primitive value directly through `IInputValue<T>.Value`. What's the best way to go about doing this? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you share the source for `ScriptableObject` please

EDIT: Oh sorry I see this is for Unity3d, I assume that's one of their classes

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use interfaces in the wrong way.
The purpose of an interface is to abstract common functionality on potentially completely different objects and not caring about the base class that implements the interface.

For instance:
You can have a **car** object and a **electric car** objects and they can both accelerate and brake. They do so in different ways but all you need to know is that they can accelerate and brake using the pedals (the interface), without you going to learn to drive a car once again.

To answer your question, I think you can use the interface as a type and call the method on the object, and in case you need to verify it is a certain type that implements that interface you can cast to it.

```cs
IInputValue<bool> myInputValue;
(ButtonInputValue) myInputValue; // This will be treated as ButtonInputValue because the class implements the IInputValue interface.
```